# Derivation of telegrapher's equations

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, phasor

I'm currently going over the derivation of the telegrapher's equations shown [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/introduction-to-the-transmission-line/), but there's a step that I'm not fully grasping.

I think I can follow some of how you get from eq.3 to eq.5:

If the current through the inductor is a sinusoid given by:
$$i(t) = Isin(\omega t + \theta)$$

Substituting this into eq.3 gives:
$$j\omega L.I(z)$$

Similarly, $$R.i(z,t)$$ becomes $$R.I(z)$$

Putting this together gives the RHS of eqn. 5:
$$-(R+j\omega L).I(z)$$

However, I simply don't understand how going from eq.3 to eq.5 the other term
gets from:

$$\frac{\partial v(z,t)}{\partial z}$$

to:

$$\frac{dV(z)}{dz} $$

If anyone can help explain in more detail what happens during the "Simplify equations 3 and 4 using Cosine phasors." step that would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's just not a partial derivative anymore because when we transform to the phasor representation the equations lose their time dependence. Hence it's a regular derivative with respect to distance down (or up depending on how things are defined) the transmission line.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to look at it is through the Fourier transform, which is what using phasors does indirectly. Hence

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} e^{-j\omega t} \ \mathrm{d}t = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} v(z, t) e^{-j\omega t} \ \mathrm{d} t = \frac{\partial V}{\partial z} (z, \omega),$$

where \$V(z, \omega)\$ is the Fourier transform of \$v(z, t)\$. Looking at a single frequency \$\omega_0\$ yields

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}(z, \omega_0) = \frac{\mathrm{d} V_{\omega_0}}{\mathrm{d} z} (z),$$

where \$V_{\omega_0} = V(z, \omega_0)\$ is a single variable function that depends only on \$z\$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. One question, why did you write:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial v}{\partial  z}e^{-j\omega t} dt $$

and not:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial v(z,t)}{\partial  z}e^{-j\omega t} dt$$

I'm a bit confused as to why the (z,t) terms aren't on the LHS but appear elsewhere.

Thanks again!

Comment: @McKendrigo Just a bit lazy I guess. We usually omit the arguments of a function when taking derivatives and writing differential equations. I decided to write them explicitly for clarity. You can take the Fourier transform in both the temporal (t) and spatial (z) dimensions. So I thought it is important to keep in mind that the z dimension is not affected by the Fourier transform. Especially because the answer to your question relates to converting a two dimensional function to a one dimensional function.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I assumed that (z,t) had been omitted on the LHS for brevity, but just wanted to clarify in case I'd missed something.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The idea of Phasors is that we can represent sines and cosines in terms of exponentials (\$e^{jx}\$) by using the relation given in Euler's formula:

$$
cos(x) + \textbf{j}sin(x) = e^{jx}
$$

Where:

$$
Im\left\{ e^{jx} \right\} = sin(x)
$$

and:

$$
Re\left\{ e^{jx} \right\} = cos(x)
$$

When they say using "cosine phasors" they imply a cosine convention where it is assumed you are taking the Real part of the function as done above.

For example if we have a co-sinusoidal time varying voltage represented by:
$$
V(t,z) = V_ocos(\omega t + \beta z)
$$

We can represent that as:
$$
V(t,z) = Re\left\{V_o e^{j(\omega t + \beta z)}  \right\} = Re\left\{V_oe^{j \beta z} e^{j\omega t}  \right\}
$$

Where:

$$
V_oe^{j\beta z} = V_o\angle \theta \ \ _{(\beta z = \theta)}
$$

is the phasor, which as you can see only varies with respect to \$z\$. The background assumption of course, is that you can add, subtract, multiply, or divide this phasor with any other phasors derived with the same "cosine convention" and plug that resulting phasor back into the template:

$$
Re\left\{[\ \ \ \ \ ] e^{j\omega t}  \right\}
$$

and you would get back the proper time varying non-phasor function.

So since the whole idea behind phasors is that we can get rid of the time varying component, do whatever operations we need, and re-introduce the time component at any point if needed, it makes sense that time \$t\$ is no longer a variable in the phasor representation.

Edit: did I misinterpret the question or state something incorrect in my answer? I wish people would leave suggestions with their downvotes.

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote, it seems clear enough to me. I just wanted to say thanks for taking the time to respond, I agree that people should leave feedback if they have an issue with an answer!